# SQLDeveloper copy database

Tags: database, testing, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-objects

I'm trying to copy a database for use in testing/developing, in SQLDeveloper I can only see the user views, the data objects are not accessible for me.

Is there anyway to copy the views only and get a dll that creates some sort of phantom structure for the data objects that are not reachable but referenced in the sql queries for those views? Problem is there are over a thousand such references,

In the example below I cannot reach the header object due too permissions, 
Example:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "TRADE"."EXCHANGE" ("MSGQUE", "MSGQUE2") AS 
  select msgque, msgque2
from  head.msgqueues;
```

I have tryed to export the views in SQL developer but when I import it in my Oracle test database the views contain error and are unusable because the data object did not get exported in the export.sql file,

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the DB version?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [expdp](http://orafaq.com/node/74) utility to perform this. You can explicitly say to grab views and tables.
Example parfile:

```
SCHEMAS=SCOTT 
INCLUDE=TABLE:"IN ('DEPT')" 
INCLUDE=VIEW
DIRECTORY=datapump 
DUMPFILE=dept.dmp 
LOGFILE=dept.log
```

Then you can impdp that parfile into the DB you wish and you will have the `TABLE` and the `VIEW` that goes in the schema. You can modify the `IN` clause to grab whatever naming scheme you would need.